# Python regex not matching at word boundary as required

Tags: python, regex

I want to match a set of patterns at "word boundary", but the patterns may have a prefix [#@] which should get matched if present.

I'm using following regex pattern in python.

```
r"\b[@#]?(abc|ef|ghij)\b"
```

Sample text is : `#abc is a pattern which should match. also abc should match. And finally @ef`

In this text only abc, abc and ef are matched without and not #abc and @ef as I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the word boundary next to `[@#]` which you made as optional. Because in this `#abc` part there is a non-word boundary `\B` exists before `#` (*not a word character*) and after the start of the line (*not a word character*) not a word boundary `\b`. Note that `\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character, vice-versa. `\B` matches between two word characters or two non-word characters.

```
r"[@#]?\b(abc|ef|ghij)\b"
```

If you put `\b` before `[@#]`, it would match strings like `foo@abc` or `bar#abc` because here there is actually a word boundary exists before `@` and `#`.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gV8gW7/1)

**Example:**

```
>>> s = "#abc is a pattern which should match. also abc should match. And finally @ef"
>>> re.findall(r'[@#]?\b(?:abc|ef|ghij)\b', s)
['#abc', 'abc', '@ef']

  #abc
 ^ ^
\B \b
```

Comment: Wow. I thought I understood regexes but this one stymied me. Can you please explain why is my answer wrong and what exactly did your solution improved on. Still confused

Answer (score 0):

The group `(@#)?` is saying that the word may begin with "@#". What you are looking for is `[@#]?` which is saying the first character is @ or #, but it is not required. If you need the match to be part of a group you could use `(@|#)?`.

Comment: Hi Alex, I'm using [] only, it was by mistake I wrote (). I've done the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I will also throw in my version of the fixed regex *without capturing group* (since you do not seem to be using them):

```
r'[@#]?\b(?:abc|ef|ghij)\b'
```

See my [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gW8jB9/1).

**EXPLANATION**: `[@#]` are non-word characters and are optional due to `?`. `\b` is *not* optional, and regex engine consumes it first, i.e. it consumes right `@` or `#`, but they are not part of the match since `\b` is always *zero-width*.

Here are more details on `\b` from [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

> The metacharacter \b is an anchor like the caret and the dollar sign.
>   It matches at a position that is called a "word boundary". This match
>   is **zero-length**.
>
> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a
>     word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last
>     character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string,
>     where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

Comment: @VaidAbhishek: Please check my explanation. It is concise, and there is a good article on that on regular-expressions.info.